# Overriding Tailwind CSS @apply Directives in a NuxtJS App

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a custom VueJS components using TailwindCSS and NuxtJS.  At times, I want to use the tailwind css `@apply` directive to style my component.  Something like this:

```
<template>
 <div class="card">
   ...
 </div>
</template>

<style>
 .card {
   @apply bg-grey-200 text-grey-800;
  }
</style>
```

I then want the capability of **overriding** those styles when I use the component.  Something like this:

```
<Card class="bg-blue-200">...</Card>
```

Now, this is technically possible -- it just requires organizing the tailing base css file in the right way.  Namely, like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
.card {
  @apply bg-grey-200 text-grey-800;
}
@tailwind utilities;
```

That is to say, `@tailwind utilities` needs to come **after** the custom class names.  The problem is that with `nuxt` it seems to be the opposite -- namely, the custom class names (and their css styles) come **after** the tailwind utilities.

How can I change this in NuxtJS?

For what it is worth, I am using the `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` module with default installation:

```
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
```

Comment: Try and write vue components with classes directly applied to them instead of using `@apply`. Adam (creator of tailwind) says himself that apply sucks. Save yourself the hassle

Comment: That's fine, but for those cases where I need/prefer to use `@apply` I would like to know how to get this to work.

Comment: It's not the answer you're looking for but it's good that it isn't working because it goes against what tailwind is. You're on your way to create your own css framework. Next is "card-title", then "card-body" and so on. Your Vue-component is already the source of truth, no need to double it down in CSS as well. Exchange the class `card` in your custom component with `bg-grey-200 text-grey-800` so it is directly in the markup. It then works as intended when you try to override the styles after importing your custom component. Just tried it on my end

Comment: I appreciate your concern and am already familiar with (and agree with) the points that you are making.  Nonetheless, I really am looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: @Rie In terms of overriding the inline class styles -- it does **not** always work.  Try different colors.  For example, try setting your component to `bg-purple-500` and then try and override it (say with `bg-orange-500`).  It does **not** work.

Comment: Can you spin up a little codesandbox with your setup? Worked earlier for me on a fresh project

Comment: Sure, here is the link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-fire-ebobw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216512/discussion-between-rie-and-moshe).

Comment: Thanks! Now @apply works fitting it between tailwind components and tailwind utilities (with laravel)

Comment: Good to hear! Great that the chat is deleted and no answer was posted either!